# regex with preg_match anything and all line breaks

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

i am not too good with regex and can't seem to find the answer

I am writing a class file to check data type and "partially/best possible sanitise" any submitted data as well as performing some other functions too. This is working on all data types (i.e emails, url's phone numbers, int/signed/un-signed, words, passwords, various date formats, basic HTML, etc)

i am having problems with trying to match "anything"* (this is the one data type i dont really need to check, but for consistency, i need it to run through the preg_match, but always want it to return true).

- when i say "anything" i want it to match any text, number, symbols AND Line Breaks. It is the line break i am having problems with

i am using :

```
define('REG_TEXT', '/^(.*)$/');
preg_match(REG_TEXT, $data)
```

this works fine on the first paragraph, but wont match past any line beaks so returns false

an example of what i want this to match (return true) would be:

```
this is a test match on anything 345 +_)(*&^%$£"!<br><html> <?php echo this i PHP;  ?>

and match this too on a new line

and match all this line too

and anything else at all
```

i am not worried about any code in-putted into the data at this point as other areas of my class are dealing with this (before this stage!).

basically i am after a regex that will match/return true on absolutely anything.
(i dont want to change to preg_match_all as this will break other aspects of the class or require me to add additional code that will be a partial repeat of code that i dont think is needed)

any advice would be greatly welcomed!

thanks
Jon

Comment: It should always match? What about `preg_match('//', $data)` if you don't need the match :)

Comment: @Jonny5 dose that actually work... i have been using regex101 and it does nothing there, but never tried it in php :-( thanks

Comment: Yea [try it in php](https://eval.in/290967) :)

Comment: @Jonny5 yes i understand it seems silly to always match, but it is just for consistency and to save writing separate functions where i dont need to check the data type (other data types of course need to match)

Comment: @Jonny5 you are right (although you knew this) it works in php.... why did i not just try this.... regex101 said it did not match anything :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
'/^(.*)$/ms'
```

You need the `m` and `s` modifiers here. http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: thank you so much, so simple yet bugged me for hours (i was placing the /m i had seen mentioned before the closing $). thanks again!